# Can not show tmage in popup box

Tags: jquery, asp.net

---

In this code i have show image in popup box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var content2 =document.getElementById('<%= ProfilePicture.ClientID %>');
T$('testclick2').onclick = function () { TINY.box.show(content2, 0, 0, 0, 1) }
```

```
<div class="button" id="testclick2"><strong>Image</strong> - <em>click here</em></div>
<asp:Image ID="ProfilePicture" runat="server" alt="Profile Pic" Width="200px" />

<asp:FileUpload ID="ProfilePictureFileUpload" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: change T$('testclick2').onclick to $('#testclick2').onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Change your code to:

```
<div class="button" id="example1"><strong>Image</strong> - <em>click here</em></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    T$('example1').onclick = function () { TINY.box.show('<asp:Image ID='img1' runat='server' width='100' height='100' alt='' />', 0, 0, 0, 1) }
</script>
```